# How windows recovery work with failure count?

Tags: windows, windows-services, restart, recovery

I am using the following command to configure the service failure recovery

```
sc failure "service" actions= ""/60000/restart/60000/run/120000 reset= 60 command = "\"c:\\windows\notepad2.exe
```

(used notepad2.exe just for testing)

From the Microsoft documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408037(v=vs.85).aspx):-

> **Actions**
>
> This field contains an array of integer values that specify the
>   actions taken by the SCM if the service fails. Separate the values in
>   the array by [~]. The integer value in the Nth element of the array
>   specifies the action performed when the service fails for the Nth
>   time.

So, what I am getting from this is the count of failure will decide the action => For first failure Actions[0] will be executed and for the second Actions[[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408037(v=vs.85).aspx)] will be executed and for all subsequent failures Actions[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wUBR.png)] will be

I have following configuration for the service for testing this behavior:-

[image]

Then I tried killing the process under which service is running by using `taskkill`.

Here is the first log 
[image]

Then I tried starting the service manually.
[image]

Then again I tried killing the service after ~ 2 mins ( => the reset count will set failure count to 0 as it is configured to 1 minute).

Here is the log for the error
[image]

In above figure, it is clear that why count is resetting to 0 because `reset` setting we have given`60 sec` and our service was running more than `2 mins`.

But the action described for recovery is wrong as Restarting the service is the action for the second failure not for the first failure.

**So why the count for failure is coming 1 but the action for recovery is the action corresponding to the second failure action?**

Answer (score 0):

I was just playing around with a similar issue, and after I set the "Reset fail count after:" to "1" day, it seems to be working.  A possible explanation is that by setting the "Reset fail count" to 1 day, it will not reset the fail count back to 0 after the first fail (which is you stopping and restarting the service manually), and lets it cycle through the rest of the actions (depending on conditions/actions).  Your mileage may vary.